# TYPO3 - MySQL - Combining a INSERT with SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert, typo3

i need an extended INSERT statement (with WHERE) to get my result in TYPO3. The standard way for INSERT with TYPO3 is this:

$res_ext=$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_INSERTquery($ext_table, $feUserRecord);

- $ext_table = 'news';

  $feUserRecord = array (
   'tx_extendnews_subscriber' => $userid_fe
  );
- tx_extendnews_subscribe is the column with the value $userid_fe

now i need an INSERT with a WHERE statement...is there a TYPO3 way or is it only with the MySQL Syntax possible?

i need this WHERE statement: SELECT * FROM news WHERE uid = post_uid

- $userid_fe = 704
- post_uid = 101

[INSERT - SELECT Link from MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html)

i try this with standard MySQL but it doesnt work for me

```
$resulting_post_id = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE uid = 101";
$res_ext="INSERT INTO news (tx_extendnews_subscriber) VALUES ('704'($resulting_post_id))";
```

Comment: Jim, can you describe in words (not in code) what you are actually trying to achieve? It might be that you don't need `INSERT ... SELECT` at all.

Comment: The INSERT and SELECT is needed because of my Tyop3 extension and the backend administration. I have 10 news and and users who can subscribe to a news. If a user subscribe to a news his id will be saved in the column tx_... where uid = 4 for example...the column has now a comma sepperated list of the ids with the users who subscribed to the news

Comment: @cascaval you are right :) I tryed it now with a third M:N table so i can use the standard way with INSERT, save comma seperated ids in a column was a bad way

Comment: Yes, 3rd table for storing the relations is a better idea. But even your original intention when you already have a news record and you want to modify it by adding another user's ID into the the news' `tx_extendnews_subscriber` column shouldn't use an `INSERT` query but an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: whoa! how are you? where are? i've been trying to figure out for a minute how to connect to my db and get specific data to a view/template. I'm lost on what's going on, but this code make more since to me than the typo3 script i'm trying to use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achive your goal with the very simple `sql_query` function:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query("INSERT INTO news (tx_extendnews_subscriber)
VALUES ('704') WHERE uid = 101");
```